# Hystrix circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix

I'm having a spring boot application which is calling iteratively a [mockserver](http://www.mock-server.com/) instance  via a hystrix command, with a fallback method.

The mockserver is configured to allways respond with status code 500. When running without having *circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds*, everything works fine, the call is done to the mockserver and then the fallback method is invoked.

After configuring *circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds* value to 5 minutes or so, I would expect that during 5 minutes no calls are done to the mockserver  all the calls  being directed to the fallback method, but that's not the case.

It looks like the *circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds* configuration is ignored.

For instance if I reconfigure the mockservice to reply with status code 200 while the iteration is still running, it would imediately print the "mockservice response",without waiting 5 minutes.

in the spring boot main application class:

```
@RequestMapping("/iterate")
  public void iterate() {
    for (int i = 1; i<100; i++ ) {
      try {
        System.out.println(bookService.readingMockService());
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
```

in the spring boot service :

```
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "ReadingMockService", commandKey = "ReadingMockService", threadPoolKey = "ReadingMockService", fallbackMethod = "reliableMock", commandProperties = {
          @HystrixProperty(name ="circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "300000") })
  public String readingMockService() {
    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:1080/askmock");
    return this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
  }
```

also the mock server is running on the same machine, being configured like :

```
new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", 1080).reset();
   new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", 1080)
           .when(request("/askmock"))
           .respond(response()
                   .withStatusCode(500)
                   .withBody("mockservice response")
                   .applyDelay());
```

Comment: sleepWindowInMilliseconds: The time in milliseconds after a {@link HystrixCircuitBreaker} trips open that it should wait before trying requests again. When mock returns 500 does it retry in 5 minutes?

Comment: No, it actually retries imediately  - that is the problem I have.I would expect , indeed to retry in 5 minutes, but instead it keeps going to mock instead of using fallback

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem :
This property (...*circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds* ) works together with another one (...*circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold* ).
If not specifically set this defaults to 20, meaning that first hystrix will try to connect 20 times the usual way and only afterwards the *sleepWindowInMilliseconds* will get activated and will go to fallback only.

Also the circuit break opens only if the percentage of failed calls exceeds *circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage*
and in the same time the total number of failed calls exceeds *circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold*, all within a window of *metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds*

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:
https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/configuration#circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds

and by looking at the source code:

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommandProperties.java

Using

`@HystrixProperty(name="hystrix.command.ReadingMockService.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds"`

should work.